# PHP, Python and java

Tags: java, php, python

I have to make a big project in my work and i need to select the appropriate language for development, i have three options (PHP , Python and Java)

I have a poor information about PHP , and intermediate information about Java and no information about Python

so i need your help to know the strength and weakness of each language and the support Of SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) in each one , and when i should choose one of them over the other options?

Comment: The answer is either "The one your team knows best" or "My favourite language".

Comment: No it is not the answer , because there is no favorite language, there are some languages that easier than others and will let you do the work faster and effective , and my choice should depend on what each language offer to me and then i can take the decision to learn this new language . Thanks

Comment: If you know what SOA is you know what language to choose.

Comment: No offence, but go read up on each language. You have 'excellent' information about all of them just waiting for you on google. As @vakio said, if you know what SOA is then you know what language to choose. Also it's 'python'. My advice would be to have a look at how each language scales and the current infrastructure you have to support it. But if you already know java, stick with it.

Answer (score 8):

Given that Java is the only language you have experience with, you should stick with it. Besides that, good software can be written in any of these languages.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know any of the languages, how do you expect to do any development in any of them?

Learning a development language enough be the leading member of the team responsible for developing a "big project" is something which take at least a full year.

If this is a case of "I need to pick a language for someone else to develop in" then the answer is: Don't.

Instead let the people responsible for doing the real development choose their language based on the details in the requirement and their own knowledge of the languages. The project can most likely be done in all 3 languages with a good result.

Comment: ...unless the language is Python, in which case you can learn it in a weekend.

Comment: Learning the language is not the problem. Learning how to design big software projects are. (And this guy obviously don't have any development expierence at all, so learning python in a week, might be a bit optimistic)

Answer (score 0):

I think Java is more efficient for you.

Comment: I don't think this answer deserves minus points because "more efficient for *you*" is pretty much correct, given the question.